# Existence of orthogonal coordinates on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry, coordinate-systems, orthogonality

This is probably a very naive question, but so far I could not find an answer:

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold. Can we always find "orthogonal coordinates" locally?

More precisely, I am asking if for every $p \in M$ there exists a neighbourhood $U$ and a diffeomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n \to U$, such that $g_{ij}=g(d\phi(e_i),d\phi(e_j))=0$ for $i \neq j$.

*Clarification:* Note that I want $g_{ij}=0$ on all $U$, not just at $p$.
Also, I allow $g_{ii} \neq g_{jj}$ for $i \neq j$ (the special case where $g_{ii}$ is independent of $i$ is called isothermal coordinates-and corresponds to conformal flatness of $U$).

Of course, this is  weaker than requiring $M$ to be conformally flat, since a (linear) map which maps an orthogonal basis to an orthogonal basis does not need to be conformal.

Comment: This only makes $g_{ij}(p)=0$ but I want $g_{ij}=0$ on all $U$.

Comment: No, because I only demand $g_{ij}=0$ for $i \neq j$. I do not assume $g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$, so $\phi$ is not necessarily an isometry.

Comment: I missed that, you want $g_{ij}(s) = 0$ for $i \ne j, s \in U$ and you allow $g_{ii}(s)$ to vary... Ok then say it clearly. And with a triangulation you should be able to see when the constraint is satisfiable.

Comment: I have edited the question, I hope it is clearer now. Can you please elaborate on the triangulation's idea? What is the obstruction you are thinking of?

Comment: Say clearly that $g_{ii}(s)$ is allowed to vary ! And no sorry I can't help more. Maybe you can find a criterion making $g_{ii}(s_0)$ to diverge as the triangulation is refined ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A Riemannian metric $g$ on an $n$-dimensional manifold is called **locally diagonalizable** if it is locally isometric to a Riemannian metric on a domain in $R^n$ with diagonal metric tensor. In dimension $n=2$ every Riemannian metric is locally diagonalizable due to existence of isothermal coordinates.

For $n\ge 3$ the problem of local diagonalizability was solved in

D. DeTurck, D. Yang, Existence of elastic deformations with prescribed principal strains and triply orthogonal systems.
Duke Math. J. 51 (1984), no. 2, 243–260.

They proved that for $n=3$ every Riemannian metric is indeed locally diagonalizable while for all $n\ge 4$ there are obstructions to local diagonalizability. For instance, a necessary condition for local diagonalizability is that $W(e_i, e_j, e_k, e_l)=0$ for every orthonormal frame with distinct $i, j, k, l$, here $W$ is the Weyl tensor.